# reading data from a number text files in R to a single text file

Tags: r

I have 198 txt files in a single directory. The filenames are stored in a list called filelist. Each file has 7 columns and a different number of rows (100-200). One file appears to have 8 columns. I used the following code

```
dat<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:n)
{
    dat<-rbind.fill(dat,read.table(filelist[i],sep=",",header=TRUE))
}
```

I get the error

> "Error in read.table(filelist[i], sep = ",", header = TRUE) : 
>     duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed".

Some posts suggest I should add rownames=NULL but I tried this and get the error message

> "Error in read.table(filelist[i], sep = ",", header = TRUE, rownames = NULL) :   unused argument (rownames = NULL)"

All guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The argument should be row.names not rownames

Comment: Are you sure you have the right separator? Were you expecting your files to have row names? Chances are something isn't formatted the way you are expecting. Maybe try `read.csv` instead since you seem to be setting `sep=","`

Comment: MrFlick, the seperator works fine, I don't think this is the issue as I can get the program to work for the first 78 files. It's only once I get to the 79th file that it stops. The 79th file has 8 columns instead of 7.

Comment: What do you want to do with the extra column in the last file? You can't really stack files with different numbers of columns. That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did see a post where someone looked at two files, realised that one had an extra column and created a dummy column in the smaller file full of NAs and then did the rbind. That seemed like a good idea but I can't figure out how to do it for so many files.

Answer (score 1):

Create three *.txt dataset (each have 100 rows and 2 columns) and save it to working directory according to filelist....

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\Sahidul.Islam\\Desktop\\R")
#[1] "C:/Users/Sahidul.Islam/Desktop/R"
getwd()

data<-matrix(rnorm(200),100,2)
colnames(data)<-c("var1","var2")

filelist<-c("dat1.txt","dat2.txt","dat3.txt")

for (i in 1:length(filelist)){
write.table(data,filelist[i],row.names=F)
    }
```

Call three *.txt datasets (created above) and bind the rows to make a compact data...

```
dat<-data.frame(read.table("dat1.txt",header=T))

for (i in 2:length(filelist))
    {
    dat<-rbind(dat,read.table(filelist[i],header=TRUE))
    }
```

Check the dimension of final dataset.

```
dim(dat)
#[1] 300   2
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for this. The issue is that when I get to file number 79 in my file list that this file has 8 instead of 7 columns. My program works fine if I go> for (i in 1:78) but doesn't work if I go >for (i in 1:80)